# Autowired bean based on annotation value type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void call();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void call() {
        System.out.println("Dog was called");
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void call() {
        System.out.println("Cat was called");
    }
}

public @interface AnimalAnnotation {
    AnimalType value() default AnimalType.DOG;
}

public enum AnimalType {
    DOG,
    CAT
}
```

In a Configuration class I am creating a bean for the two type of Animal inheritors:

```
@Configuration
public class AnimalConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Animal initDog() {
       return new Dog();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Animal initCat() {
       return new Cat();
    }
}
```

My intention here is to autowired a bean with dynamic type as it follows:

```
public class Main {
    @Autowired
    @AnimalAnnotation(AnimalType.CAT)
    private Animal animal; // the instance should be the Cat one
    public void perform() {
        animal.call(); // In the console we should see "Cat was called".
    }
}
```

This is a example code which describes my intention, which it could be wrong.
Can be this be implemented and what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a `@Qualifier`? That may work. You would have to give your beans a name like

```java
@Bean("cat")
public Animal initCat() {
    return new Cat();
}
```

and then when autowiring you would have:

```java
@Autowired
@Qualifier("cat")
private Animal animal;
```

Comment: Thanks @burm87. This is another approach indeed. But can we do it via custom annotations?

Comment: Yes I think that's doable. You can define your own annotation and define the behaviour you want for it. For sure it's a bit more tricky.

Comment: I couldn't find information how to do that. Could you please give me such?

Comment: @JordanBorisov check this guide https://www.baeldung.com/java-custom-annotation it's gonna show you how to define your own annotation and add the processor related to it. In your case your will have to access the spring context and get the bean of the right type (cat, dog, lizard). I may have time later on in the day, but if you could give it a try first it would be great!

Comment: I will use the Qualifier way and I will accept this answer because it is more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way will be to use `@Qualifier` annotation, e.g.:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("initDog")
```